# How to Handle large input size in java?

Tags: java, user-input

I am solving a problem in java where input constraints are given as follows:

```
1 <= T <= 10000  
1 <= A <= B <= 10^18
```

I want to ask, what is the suitable data type in java which is in range of `10^18`, so I can pass all sample test cases.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html => a simple long is more than enough for your use case

Comment: Except that the question is misphrased, and the querant wants to perform arbitrary math upon these -- meaning that there's actually no defined maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Try the java `BigInteger`. Its size is 32 bytes and it should be enough

Comment: `BigInteger` can handle arbitrarily large numbers, it is only limited by the amount of available memory.

Comment: BigInteger is stored as an int array. Max length of an array is Integer.MAX_VALUE => limit of BigInteger is: (2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: `BigInteger` has no size limit.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan - there's always a limit, see my comment

Comment: @StijnGeukens, yes we also have year limits in our life, but conceptually `Biginteger` has no limit. Yes I agree with your comment, but in this case it is not such actual.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan: I tend to agree, you will probably exhaust your RAM before reaching the limit.

Comment: @Stijn: That is implementation specific. According to the specs it has no upper bound, and can be treated as such for all practical (and impractical) purposes.